# Lock orientation on Storm

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-storm

I need to lock my application in portrait mode on a Storm(and Strom 2) device.
I use `Ui.getUiEngineInstance().setAcceptableDirections(Display.DIRECTION_PORTRAIT);` for this.

Here is the problem:

> The screen direction only changes once
>   the device is rotated to a direction
>   supported by the provided direction
>   parameter.

([source](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/UiEngineInstance.html#setAcceptableDirections%28int%29))

If the user has the device in landscape mode and opens the application, the application will open in landscape and will only lock to portrait mode when/if the user rotates the device to portrait mode.

Is there any way to force the application in portrait mode even in the case I described above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have made a static method that I call from my application's `main()` method.

See the full code in my answer to this question: [How to fix alignment for vertical and portrait screen in BlackBerry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8076853/how-to-fix-alignment-for-vertical-and-portrait-screen-in-blackberry/8078882#8078882)

Answer (score 0):

It can be solved by creating a custom class which extends MainScreen class which accepts the nextScreenObject as an argument in the constructor

and then by using

UiApplication.getUiApplication.pushModalScreen(nextScreenObj);
//This would lock the screen

So whenever you push any screen create an object of this custom class and send the screen object as an argument to this constructor

Eg: Let NewCustomClass be your custom class which extends MainScreen
then while pushing a new screen you can

NextScreen nextScreenObj = new NextScreen(..args..);
  NewCustomClass pushObj =  new NewCustomClass(nextScreenObj);

Let me know if the problem is solved.